# Vivid / Poor performance on Football Manager 2014

Tags: games, performance, intel, steam

When I launch a new game, I only have one star for performance, even for 1 league only, despite a good configuration for this (i don't want 3D view of matches):

Xubuntu Vivid x64 /
Intel Celeron J1900 4x2ghz /
Intel Graphics with shared memory (up to 2Gb) /
4Go DDR3 /
Steam Linux version

I can launch other native games from Steam like Crusader Kings 2 or Half Life in full without problem. Maybe because Football Manager is a 32-bit game only ...

Comment: It's native Linux version from Steam, like the 2 others games

Comment: You might want to update your question with that information ;)